# Is there a way to add a Google Calendar ACL for all of workspace users' primary E-Mails?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I am an admin on two Google Workspaces. I am looking for a way to sync both organizations' calendars so that a user from workspace A can hop into a calendar of any user from workspace B and schedule a meeting in his free time. Scouring the API more and more I am losing hope. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You may check this related [online resource](https://support.robinpowered.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001164606-How-to-allow-outside-Google-domains-to-book-your-resource-calendars) as this discusses the sharing of each user's calendars to another domain users outside of their organization by applying an ACL using the **CalendarList API**. Have you also tried reaching out to [Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) to get if there are other options/workarounds for Calendar resource sharing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look into that resource. Support wasn't helpful